# SQL Server agent job scripts

Tags: sql-server

Being a newbie to database migration, can I script all the database jobs one by one and run them against a new server to create these jobs?

If not, why do we use these SQL job scripts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at the recently posted question about the same topic: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64084/copy-maintenance-plans-to-a-different-server.

Answer (score 3):

> > can I script all the database jobs one by one and run them against a new server to create these jobs?

Yes

But anything dependent will need to exist, i.e. users, proxies, if there is a path in the task it needs to work against the new server.

Normally there is some kind of migration process, i.e. "I'll need to change all D drives to E, I'll need to change the proxy name" etc.

Why don't you try one and see.

Comment: Thanks ElectricLlama.You are right. ALso, can you please tell me how to move the SSIS package within the jobs from one server to another. which would be the best way to do that. Googled it ,got too many information and choices regarding this. Please help

Comment: You should ask another question and provide specifics, i.e. are your packages stored in the file system? What protection level do they use? What is your current issue - provide exact error messages if you have any. Please don't ask general question without providing specifics. Also please don't ask without trying something first.

Comment: Ok Got you. Here what I did, Scripted and saved all jobs > Saved all the SSIS package from sourceDb as dtsx > moved them into destination server (since we are not changing the Server name,no editing) > ran the saved scripts against these packages. Cannot run these packages until the source is closed. So, like I said, being a newbie in DBA, I just want to know, is this the correct method to follow. anyways thank you

Comment: "Cannot run these packages until the source is closed." ? Is that an error you get? From where? SQL Agent? You should open a new question and explain in detail what you want to do, what you did and any errors that occurred. I assume from your response that your packages are saved in SQL Server, not in the file system.