# Create maintenance plan using SQL script without using the wizard

Tags: sql-server

How to create maintenance plan using sql script with out maintenance plan wizard. Please don't suggest olahallengren solution. His script is not exact relpica of maintenance plan.This means, he created only jobs but not maintenanceplan name in management-->maintenaceplan fodler.So, let me know,  Is it possible or not to create maintenance plan using sql script?

Answer (score 4):

The [answer by Riccardo Bassilichi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112434) on [Copy maintenance plans to a different server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/64084) might offer a solution.

You could insert it in your own table and create and specify your own name
like the following (original by Riccardo Bassilichi, changed a little by me):

```
INSERT INTO msdb.dbo.sysssispackages
SELECT        
'CustomName' as name,  --name of copied maintenance plan
 newid() as id ,  --new id for the maint plan
description, 
createdate, 
folderid, 
ownersid, 
cast(
    cast(

            cast(
                CAST(packagedata AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS varchar(max)
            )
    as XML) 
as VARBINARY(MAX)) as packagedata, 
packageformat, 
packagetype, 
vermajor, 
verminor, 
verbuild, 
vercomments, 
verid, 
isencrypted, 
readrolesid, 
writerolesid

FROM
msdb.dbo.sysssispackages AS sysssispackages_1
WHERE        
(name = 'YourMaintenancePlanName')
```

Change the old and new maintenance plan names to your maintenance plan and the desired name of the new maintenance plan.

Don't forget to delete the schedule of the newly created maintenance plan, schedule it again, and save.